# npm is not recognized as internal or external

Tags: npm-install

I have installed node js(Windows 7) but it's showing npm not recognized as internal or external..I set the global and local paths to C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm still it's showing the same error.

Comment: Have you restarted cmd after the install?

Comment: yes i did but it still showing the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm not recognized as internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50253040/npm-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

Type on you CMD:
`where npm`
and you'll see the path probably is:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

That is what you must have on your path.
Also you can try to run the command from that path...

Comment: done with it but now it's showing ng is not recognized as internal or external while creating project with ng new in cmd