# npm not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am getting npm not recognized as internal or external command.
User variable Path is set to : %AppData%\npm;C:\Program_Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm;C:\Program_Files\nodejs;

I have tried with npm version 5.0 and 3.10.8 .

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S84RQ.png)

Comment: Reinstall node.js, it comes is installed with it

Comment: @EthanBrimhall I have reinstall nodejs .Also while installing nodejs  it throws error saying check path you are installing is accessible

Comment: The problem might be with your variable path. Try searching your computer for npm and copy the address of where it is located and copy into variable path.

Comment: I have pasted path variable in question itself.is it right?nodejs is installed in "Program Files" folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I solved by below steps:
1.run echo %comSpec% in command prompt or terminal
2.Check whether below entry exists 
C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cmd.exe
3.Then remove above entry from system environment variable.
```